# Partial skeleton tracking using Kinect: lower body tracking

Tags: kinect, openni, openkinect

I am interested in tracking leg and foot positions of a human body, with the upper body being outside the field of view. Since version 1.5, Microsoft's Kinect SDK offers a "[seated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.skeletontrackingmode.aspx)" skeleton tracking mode, where lower body joints are disregarded. Apparently, a special mode for the opposite (tracking the lower torso) seems not available. However, there is this [FrameEdges Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.frameedges.aspx) which can seemingly be used to "Find out how much of a user's body is visible [...]". So does that mean that the SDK suppports tracking of the lower body joints with the top of the user's body being outside the field of view and using the default tracking mode? Does anyone have experience with this task and have any tips?

Apparently OpenNI offers partial skeleton tracking but I wasn't able to find more details on that. Anyone can help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with the [NiSimpleSkeleton](https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI/blob/master/Samples/NiSimpleSkeleton/NiSimpleSkeleton.cpp) sample.

If should be a matter of replacing the

`XN_SKEL_PROFILE_ALL`

constant with

`XN_SKEL_PROFILE_LOWER`

in the [sample](https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI/blob/master/Samples/NiSimpleSkeleton/NiSimpleSkeleton.cpp#L198).

Comment: +1 Thanks for your hint! I'll wait for some more answers before accepting yours.